# Draw triangle as subview to right corner of table cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, tableview, subview

I would like to draw a triangle **using CGRect instead of UIImageView** and add it as subview to the right corner of some particular table cells similar to how it's done on the WWDC app.

Any advice is welcomed. :)

[image: WWDC App Screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An easy way can be to have different UIImageView's containing a colored-triangle, then selecting the different image to display according to certain values/preference that you setup.
Taken from here:[Drawing a triangle in UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073246/drawing-a-triangle-in-uiview)

You will need to do some math to calculate the correct points, but this is the general way of drawing a triangle. You can just create your own subclass of UIView (call it CornerTriangle) and then add it to the cell while settings its color to match your needs.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint   (ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));  // top left
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));  // mid right
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));  // bottom left
    CGContextClosePath(ctx);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1, 1, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

Comment: Hello :) I'd like to draw the triangle using CGRect instead of adding UIImageViews. I've just edited my question accordingly. :)

Comment: Of course this custom view should have a property for the color and that property would be used in the `drawRect:` method to draw the triangle.

Comment: @KeithOYS Hey Keith, if my solution helped you please upvote/approve. Thanks bud!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method to your UiTableviewCell Class . This is the right effect you are looking for :

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint   (ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));  
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));  
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect)-25, CGRectGetMinY(rect));  
    CGContextClosePath(ctx);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1, 1, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```