# How to add a triangle button

Tags: iphone, ios6

I know this question has been asked earlier also but doesn't meet my requirements and not proper satisfactory answers found, so asking again. I want a button in triangular shape. I have no idea about it how can it be achieved. I searched and found one interesting solution. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697614/how-to-draw-a-triangle-programmatically)  is the link.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextMoveToPoint   (ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));  // top left
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));  // mid right
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));  // bottom left
CGContextClosePath(ctx);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1, 1, 0, 1);
CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

How to use this solution i don't know. Can anyone guide for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use a UIButton with a transparent background and a triangle image?

Comment: If you are wanting to use the drawRect function then you need to look into subclassing UIButton

Comment: Please provide some example if you can.